# Regex for get all keyword and description meta tag contents

Tags: php, regex

I want to use `preg_match_all()` function for parse a html page and get all keyword and description meta tag contents but i cannot write a regex for this action , help me please

Comment: Don't do that. Use a parser.

Comment: Don't use a parser. Use a built-in. PHP has [`get_meta_tags()`](http://php.net/get_meta_tags).

Comment: @mario I have a html string and this function require a url

Comment: Well just use `$url = "data:,$htmlstring";` then. Take care that unlike the brittle DOM method it only extracts tags from the `<head>` area.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\<meta\s*name="(\w*)"\s*content="(.*)"
```

(Edit: changed per georg's suggestion).

This would capture the name and the content of the attribute separately in one array.

The function call should look something like this.

```
preg_match_all("/\<meta.name="(\w*)".content="(.*)"/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Output would look something like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials"
        [1] => <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript"
        [2] => <meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => description
        [1] => keywords
        [2] => author
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Free Web tutorials
        [1] => HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript
        [2] => Hege Refsnes
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a parser:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($your_html);

$nodes = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('meta');
$metas = array();

foreach($nodes as $node)
    $metas[strtolower($node->getAttribute('name'))] = $node->getAttribute('content');

print_r($metas);
```

Another option is [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php), but it's broken in at least two ways:

- it requires a filename, so if you have a string, you have to write it to a temporary file first
- it's rather silly and doesn't parse the structure properly, for example, if some meta tag is commented out, it will still return it

So, stick with the DOM parser, or use other methods outlined in [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: +1 for good answer and to nullify the downvote. It's a pity that people downvotes without comments.